# SELECT with multiple COUNTs

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle, given the following data

```
+------------+-----+
+ STATUS     | GRP +
+------------+-----+
+ Pass       | A   +
+ Fail       | A   +
+ Pass       | A   +
+ Pass       | B   +
+ Fail       | B   +
+ Pass       | C   +
+ bad        | C   +
+------------------+
```

I would like to get the following result

```
+---------+-------+-------+-------+
+ GRP     | Total + Pass  + Fail  +
+---------+-------+-------+-------+
+ A       | 3     + 2     + 1     +
+ B       | 2     + 1     + 1     +
+ C       | 2     + 1     + 0     +
+---------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Is it possible to do it with one SQL query or do I need to make three separate SQL calls?

Comment: This is a pivot table. You may want to take a look to this: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_pivot_examples.htm

Comment: @Barranka - This isn't a pivot question... why the link?

Comment: Why is there a `+` sign instead of `|` as the column separators? Confusing typo

Comment: @MostyMostacho - not all keyboards have `|` in an easy to find location.

Comment: @Hogan This *is* a pivot table. Row headers: Distinct values of the `GRP` column; Column headers: Distinct values of the `STATUS` column; Data values: Count of occurrences for each `(GRP,STATUS)` combination. If that's not a pivot table, then what is? (And, as far as I know, Oracle has a built-in instruction for pivot table construction)

Comment: @Barranka - Won't work, he wants `STATUS = bad` to be counted in total.  Using an extra table this way would miss these.  Also, it is clearly a grouping issue so why make and extra table and make it more complicated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do it like this using SQL grouping, along with the COUNT() and SUM() aggregate functions.  For SUM we use a standard SQL "trick" of an embedded CASE statement.

```
select GRP, COUNT(*) as Total, 
            SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Pass' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Pass,
            SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Fail' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Fail
from table
group by GRP
```

---

**Average**
Use the same tricks to get average knowing that the AVG aggregate will *ignore* any parameter which is null.

```
select GRP, COUNT(*) as Total, 
            SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Pass' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Pass,
            SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Fail' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Fail,
            AVG(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Pass' THEN Score ELSE null END) AS PassAVG,
            AVG(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Fail' THEN Score ELSE null END) AS FailAVG,
from table
group by GRP
```

Comment: looks good. what's the standard SQL trick if it were average instead of count?

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano - so an average against another column score for pass vs fail?

Comment: Ya I was thinking it's just a matter of doing the sum with the value else 0 and then dividing by the count using the sum function you had

Comment: the only problem I have to watch out for is if the denominator is zero

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you were looking for?

```
SELECT s.GRP, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stats ss WHERE s.GRP = ss.GRP) AS Total,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stats ss WHERE s.GRP = ss.GRP AND ss.status = 'Pass')
        AS Pass,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stats ss WHERE s.GRP = ss.GRP AND ss.status = 'Fail')
        AS Fail
FROM stats s GROUP BY GRP;
```